# how does the nested \def in \def\inst{\beamer@insttitle}\def\and{\beamer@andtitle}

Tags: macros, code, package-writing, documentclass-writing

I am trying to understand the following code:

```
\def\author{\@dblarg\beamer@author}
\long\def\beamer@author[#1]#2{%
  \def\insertauthor{\def\inst{\beamer@insttitle}\def\and{\beamer@andtitle}#2}%
}
```

Patterns similar to the above example turn up in [`beamerbasetitle.sty`](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/main/base/beamerbasetitle.sty).

#### What I understood so far

```
\def\author{\@dblarg\beamer@author}
```

This line is explained in the SE post [`q/56329`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56329). We need this line to define `\beamer@author` in a way that it handles the cases `\author{abc}` and `\author[xyz]{abc}`.

```
\long\def\beamer@author[#1]#2{%
```

This line (re-)defines the `\beamer@author` command (?)

```
\def\insertauthor{\def\inst{\beamer@insttitle}\def\and{\beamer@andtitle}#2}%
```

This line is the line that confuses me the most. The `\def\insertauthor` defines the `\insertauthor` command, and, from what I got from the question [`q/541515`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/541515), a call like `\insertauthor{J. Doe}`
would then expand to

```
\def\inst{\beamer@insttitle}\def\and{\beamer@andtitle}J. Doe
```

Correct? Why do we need to add `\def\inst{\beamer@insttitle}\def\and{\beamer@andtitle}`? I feel like

```
\def\insertauthor{#2}%
```

would also do the job. I also noticed the following part in [`beamerbasetitle.sty`](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/main/base/beamerbasetitle.sty).:

```
% Aux commands for \author
\def\beamer@insttitle#1{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\def\beamer@andtitle{\quad}
```

I would like to understand how the nested `\def`s are expanded and how to read the initial example.

Comment: `a call like \insertauthor{J. Doe}` no `\insertauthor` is not defined to take an argument, see the line you show, it is `\def\insertauthor{...` not `\def\insertauthor#1{...`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for this explanation. If I understand correctly, the line `\def\insertauthor{..` only defines the command `\insertauthor` which expands to `\def\inst{\beamer@insttitle}\def\and{\beamer@andtitle}J. Doe` if I call `\author{J. Doe}`?

Comment: You can give more than one author, e.g. `\author[Hemaspaandra et al.]{L. Hemaspaandra\inst{1} \and T. Tantau\inst{2}}`, your two \def ensure that \inst and \and then have locally the needed definition.

Comment: yes and so the author name specified in `\author` isn't directly used but whatever beamer template is being used can use `\insertauthor` where it wants to insert the author name

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for pointing out this instructive example. Found it now also in the [beameruserguide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). It makes completely sense to specify `\inst` and `\and` for a command like `\author` that should be able to handle these commands in its argument.