# In Latex's commands, why do we only use lowercase?

Tags: macros

In Latex's commands,
I see that all the commands are in lowercase?
This is very difficult to distinguish the words?
Why don't we use CamelCase?
Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Your observation is wrong. There are `\Phi` and the like in title case and `\DeclareRobustCommand` etc. in camel case. It's very dependent on the subset of LaTeX you use whether you encounter these, though.

Comment: lowercase is easier to type, so most user commands stick to it. Camel case is used for package commands.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48207/1090

Comment: We don't. Very often it does not matter, so we stick to the lower case commands, but sometimes it does: cf. `\large`, `\Large` and `\LARGE`.

Comment: Sometimes it is practical to use two commands one starting with and one without a capital where the difference between the commands *is* if the result should have a capital, like `\sigma` and `\Sigma`, or `\textcite` and `\Textcite`.

Comment: In packages sometimes I create a sort-of namespace with a lowercase prefix on all the commands. E.g., a package for writing CVs has lots of commands like `\cvName` or `\cvItem`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most LaTeX document commands are lowercase, though this is not universal: in the core there are things like `\Phi`, as pointed out in comments, but there are also packages which add some mixed or uppercase commands. Probably the most obvious mixed-case command is `\LaTeX` itself! However, one might say that the pattern for document commands is as you say that they are lowercase other than where there is a direct semantic meaning to uppercasing some of the characters: the commands for Greek/Russian uppercase characters, logos, etc.

Design/package commands tend to be CamelCase. This makes them 'stand out' as being aimed primarily at package authors. For example, in a package one might see `\ProvidesPackage` or `\DeclareRobustCommand`, etc. These would not normally be common in a document.

There are a very limited number of all-uppercase commands. The most obvious to me is `\SI` from my `siunitx` package, but there are others. In general, all-uppercase tends to be avoided. This makes names in this area useful for example for debugging: the LaTeX team often use `\ERROR` as a place-holder when creating error conditions, for example.

Comment: Personally, I normally use camelCase for identifiers that start with a lowercase letter, and call commands such as `\DeclareRobustCommand`, PascalCase.

Comment: Is \DocumentMetadata considered to be a "design/package command"? Why?

Answer (score 5):

It’s an arbitrary convention, but it’s important to be consistent.  If Donald E. Knuth had sometimes used lowercase, sometimes camelCase, sometimes PascalCase, for TeX primitives, it would’ve been much harder to remember whether the command is `\baselineskip`, `\baselineSkip` or `\BaselineSkip`, or maybe `\BaseLineSkip`.  The few exceptions in the original design are very logical, such as `\Theta` being a capital `\theta` and `\TeX` matching the typography of the logo.  Leslie Lamport also originally stuck to this for LaTeX (with the exception previously mentioned, `\LaTeX`, following the example of `\TeX`).

Most newer LaTeX kernel commands in fact follow a different convention, either `\PascalCase` or `\scope_snake_case_type:xyz` for anything in expl3 syntax.  So, `\newcommand`, but `\DeclareRobustcommand`, and you just have to remember whether any given command is older or newer than the change.  Here, it helps to remember that `\Declare` commanda are almost always newer.  With things like `\IfFileExists`, well, they couldn’t very well have clashed with the TeX primitive `\if`, could they?  But with commands like `\providecommand` and `\ProvidesPackage`, you just have to memorize them case by case.   Some other packages (such as `ucharclasses`) use `\camelCase`, and this has bitten me more than once.  You might or might not agree with this decision, but at least if you know which module the command is from and which convention it uses, you can keep it straight.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! ! 1 up vote.